# Change a process description at run time

Tags: win32-process

I have an C win32 application that starts other apps by using the CreateProcess(). Each of the new processes get a unique port number and other stuff. My question is there anyway to add, for example the port number, to the new process description at run time? I want this to to be able to separate the processes by looking at the Task manager > Processes > Description column.

Please understand I am talking about run time not compile time.

with regards,

Ehsan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Description value is retreived from a process's version resource, which cannot be changed while the process is running.