# ProcessStartInfo change process description (Displayed in task manager)

Tags: c#, processstartinfo

I am currently running a process with the name notepad.exe through C# using ProcessStartInfo class, I want to change the process's description (The one where you can see in task manager) just for fun, Is it possible to do so and how?

The application I want to run is a third party application

Here is how I run my notepad.exe:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WiLMA\Dependencies\winpmem-1.4\winpmem_1.4.exe";
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";

        var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This might be the same as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914101/changing-a-programs-process-name-in-task-manager`

Comment: He did more on process name, my problem is on process description =)
Thanks though for the read

Comment: Then it is the same as this : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408496/how-can-i-set-the-task-manager-description-for-my-program`. :-)

Comment: but my problem is changing the process description of a program that already exists (i didn't code the executable), not my program itself =)

Comment: Just to be clear : You want to change the description of a 3rd party application and not one that you have coded?

Comment: Yes =) (uses your words to edit my post)

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340477/change-a-process-description-at-run-time

Comment: I think you would require some P/Invoke calls. You can maybe lookup the SetFileInformationByHandle() in kernel32.dll and call it with the appropriate parameters where your handle would be process.MainWindowHandle. But I would not be surprised if it did not work. Maybe somebody can give some WMI way of doing it.